# Javascript Regex for change Image Attribute

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem regarding regex.

Actually I want to add some value, like random no, in the end of img path and I am using regex for that. Here is my code:

`retVal.replace(/src=\"([^\"]*)\"/,'<img src=$1?cache=fasle');`

However, it's not working properly, please help me.

Comment: You haven't included you code. I suspect you've pasted it in without code-formatting it in the editor. Can you past the code in and then format it using the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: You are missing your code. Stop with ASAP, it feels like a direct order. We are not here to get ordered, but because we like it. Don't use a signature, SO will add one for you automatically.

Comment: why don't you use javascript setAttribute()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var retVal = '<img src="test.com" />';
retVal = retVal.replace(/src=\"([^\"]*)\"/,'src="$1?cache=false"');
```

[**Check a live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/kbw4n/)

Answer (score 1):

- Select the IMG element using ID/NAME/whatever .
- Get the value of the src attribute
- Append the random number/string/whatever to the result of step 2.
- Write the result of step 3 as the src attribute .

Why regex ?

Comment: I am guessing it might be a string, meaning not actual DOM elements, but that's just my guess.

Comment: seems like a reasonable guess .